# PictureBox not displaying in form C#

Tags: c#, controls

I have the following code:

```
    foto = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(foto)).BeginInit();
    foto.BackgroundImage = global::Catalogo_Digital.Properties.Resources.voltar;
    foto.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
    foto.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(85, 85);
    foto.Name = "foto";
    foto.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1000, 800);
    foto.TabIndex = 0;
    foto.TabStop = false;
internal System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox foto;
```

The problem is that this picturebox called "foto" is not displaying when I debug it, it's just invisible, I don't know. I just wanted to create a "internal" or "public" picturebox without making it in designer mode, only using codes.

Comment: That's a pretty random snippet of code.  Is it really missing EndInit() and this.Controls.Add(foto)?

Comment: Thanks Hans. The code was missing this.Controls.Add(foto);. I just added it and now it's displaying it, thanks.